# How put Google MapView in UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to put Google MapView in `UIView` but I get nothing displayed.

My code,

*.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnLocate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView_;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mapView;

@end
```

*.m

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    self.mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    self.mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView = self.mapView_;
```

Thanks.

**Solution**

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];

    // Indicating the map frame bounds
    self.mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.bounds camera: camera]; 
    self.mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    // Add as subview the mapview
    [self.mapView addSubview: self.mapView_];
```

So, i got the solution. Thanks anyway.

Best regards.

Comment: post that as answer then accept which will be really helpful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];

    // Indicating the map frame bounds
    self.mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.bounds camera: camera]; 
    self.mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    // Add as subview the mapview
    [self.mapView addSubview: self.mapView_];
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially in the storyboard, for the corresponding View(UIVIew) you're going to show the Google Map, you have to set the class as `GMSMapView` in identity inspector.

This is how view controller would look like in Swift 3.

```
class GMapsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapContainerView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)

       let marker = GMSMarker()
       marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
       marker.title = "Sydney"
       marker.map = mapContainerView

       mapContainerView.moveCamera(GMSCameraUpdate.setCamera(camera))


       }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to bridge this to react native?

Comment: @Jarrett You should be able to but on react native there should be libraries already for this.

Comment: @ Hashan Senevirathe Yeah i have heard of a library called `react-native-maps`, however it is not maintained anymore. So was just wondering if anyone have a simple example? Maybe not even for google maps but just to display a simple view. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for the reply too!

Comment: @Jarrett Ah, I have used react-native-maps in a react-native project before. It is maintained and this project is active. Because I can see recent commits as well. Just that they are looking for folks to help maintain the project. So you can use this library easily.