# IOS Google Map SDK - Google Map not updating to current location

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I am trying to implement my current location within a sub view using `Google Map SDK for IOS`. I am trying to implement the GMSMapView as an IBOutlet.

***My header file has the code***

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <Google-Maps-iOS-SDK/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

 @interface TripLandingViewController : UIViewController

 @property IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;

 @end
```

***My .m file has the code***

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tile.png"]];
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = TRUE;



    NSLog(@"\n\n\n My Location is %f,%f \n\n\n",self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude,self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                           longitude:self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:10];
    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

No matter, what hardcoded value i provide as parameters for coordinates in camera. I am getting the wrong location (here UK) which is not at all updating.

But Instead when i tried

```
    self.View = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

I was able to load correct map View in the Main View with correct location coordinates.

***I tried all the answers on adding Google Map to SubViews through stackoverflow.***

[Cannot put a google maps GMSMapView in a subview of main main view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417811/cannot-put-a-google-maps-gmsmapview-in-a-subview-of-main-main-view)

[How to set the frame for mapview - in google GMSMap for iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675402/how-to-set-the-frame-for-mapview-in-google-gmsmap-for-ios6)

[How put Google MapView in UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177897/how-put-google-mapview-in-uiview)

[Google Maps iOS SDK, Getting Current Location of user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967496/google-maps-ios-sdk-getting-current-location-of-user)

But nothing seems to work. Please Help since I am new to IOS Programming.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:0 longitude:0 zoom:15];
 self.mapView.camera = camera;
```

instead of using:

```
self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

I'm not totally sure why, but this method works when your `GMSMapView` is a subview of your `UIViewController`.