# Google Maps in a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, maps

I am trying to put a google maps view into a `UIView` in my app. The `UIView` was created inside a `UIViewController` in the stroryboard and I added I few auto layout constraints.

I am able to load the map inside the `UIView` based in the answer of this post: 
[How to put Google Map in a custom UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078485/how-to-put-google-map-in-a-custom-uiview)

However, when I load the view in `(void)viewDidLoad` method, it seems to completely ignore the constraints and maps get out the screen in some iPhones sizes (I could check this using Debug View Hierarchy). If I do not load the `(void)viewDidLoad` but instead, do this when the user press a button (ig.: IBAction), everything works perfectly.

I'm using exactly the same code in both situation. I've no ideia why the behaviour is different. Any help?

The code that I am using to load the maps into `UIView`:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                        longitude:longitude                                                                 zoom:13];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:_mapsView.bounds camera:camera];
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
[self.mapsView addSubview:mapView_];
```

Comment: change from `viewDidLoad` in `viewWillApear`; in `viewDidLoad` the constrains are not “ready” yet :)

Comment: Thank you for your replay, @TonyMkenu. I tried that but it is still with the same problem.

Comment: hmm.. you are using Autolayout.. it will not work with `addSubview`; try to change last line to `self.mapsView = mapView_; or.... here another example (with demo project) http://stackoverflow.com/a/26778538/1702413

Comment: I found solution in here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177897/how-put-google-mapview-in-uiview kindly to take alook